# CMV Passing search value via URL

Tags: configurable-map-viewer, url

I have created an app using the CMV and I've incorporated the Search and Attribute widgets as well.

I would like to pass parameters via the URL to achieve similar results as in my old ArcIMS application here:  http://ims.wvgs.wvnet.edu/wvog/viewer.htm?ActiveLayer=12&Query=API%3D4704971001&QueryZoom=Yes&Layers=0000111100001000

My new CMV map (in testing) is here: http://www.wvgs.wvnet.edu/gis/og/wvog/index.html

So for instance, I am looking at a well with an API number (identifier) of 4704971001.  It works when I do a search for that number in the Search box for my CMV map.   I'm not sure how to pass that number into the URL to achieve similar results as in my IMS map.  I was assuming appending something like ?Search=API%3D4704971001 would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one simple example of how to pass a value in the url to the AttributesTable widget:

example configuration file: https://github.com/tmcgee/cmv-widgets/blob/master/config/queryStringSearch.js

live demo: http://tmcgee.github.io/cmv-widgets/demo.html?config=queryStringSearch&fips=08101